# for loop never ends with a matrix

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix, random

```
for sublistas in matriz:
    for espacios in matriz:
        ran = random.choice([p_vivo, p_muerto])
        matriz.append(ran)
```

I am trying to with a matrix with 2 random choices: p_muerto or p_vivo
The problem is, the loop never ends. I think it is because it keeps overwriting the elements of the matrix, so it keeps going indefinitely.

What can I do?

Comment: Why are you looping twice over the same matrix? What is the desired result  supposed to be?

Comment: Fix your indentation. The second `for` loop has to be indented in the first one.

Comment: The indentation is fine. It just looks different on this site.

Comment: I am looping twice because it a 15x15 matrix. I need to enter each row and then each element.

Comment: You're not looping over rows and columns, you're looping over all the elements in both loops.

Comment: I meant you should fix the indentation on this site so it matches the indentation in the real code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the endless loop occured because you're modifing original matrix adding a new element.

You can create copy of that matrix and operate on copied matrix - the original will stay safe and will be not modified.

In case you want to operate with original matrix - you just can loop through the copy.

Comment: Since he wants to append to the matrix, he should probably be looping over the copy.

Answer (score 1):

To loop over a list of lists, you need to do:

```
for sublist in matriz:
    for element in sublist:
```

And if you're appending to the list in the loop, you should loop over copies. And you shouldn't be appending to the top-level list, you should append to a sublist. Or maybe you should be making new sublists and appending to them. It's not clear what your desired result is.

```
for sublist in matrix[:]:
    for element in sublist[:]:
        ran = random.choice([p_vivo, p_muerto])
        sublist.append(ran)
```

This will change the list from 15x15 to 15x30